# Would someone help me understand the Ruby manual's example of str.counts?

Tags: ruby

In every other example I see, str.count is quite simple. It just counts the instances of the parameter in the string. But the example of the method given in the Ruby manual seems incomprehensible (see below). It doesn't even use parenthesis! Could anyone help elucidate this for me?

```
a = "hello world"
a.count "lo"            »   5
a.count "lo", "o"       »   2
a.count "hello", "^l"   »   4
a.count "ej-m"          »   4
```

Comment: Why would it matter whether the example uses parentheses or not? There is no semantic difference between using parentheses or not.

Comment: The parentheses can be optional sometimes in ruby. `a.count "lo"` is equivalent to `a.count("lo")`. There's certain cases where you need to use parentheses, but for these examples it's understood that everything following the method name is an argument

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's counting the number of [occurences](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-count) of the letters you passed in as an argument

```
a.count("lo") # 5, counts [l, o]
hello world
  ***  * *

# counts all [h, e, o], but not "l" because of the caret
a.count "hello", "^l" # 4
hello world
**  *  *

a.count "ej-m" # counts e, and the characters in range j, k, l, m
hello world
 ***     *
```

There's a couple special characters:

- caret ^ is negated.
- The `-` means a range
- The `\` escapes the other two and is ignored

Comment: Excellent answer (except for the misspelled word)!